# Unwanted right-margin on mobile website, leading to horizontal scroll

Tags: css, mobile, width, margin, padding

My website body is full-width and looks great on large screens, but when it gets down to 350 pixels wide, a strange right-margin comes in the way, creating horizontal scroll. I tried the usual suggestions: setting the body's margins and paddings to 0, as well as "max-width: 100%", with no success.

Here is the website: [www.latelierdegaia.ch](http://www.latelierdegaia.ch)

Can anybody help? Thank you very dearly!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting a horizontal scrollbar at 350px is because of this rule:

```html
.custom-logo-link img {
    max-width: 350px;
}
```

If you change that to `max-width: 300px;` then it's gonna look fine even on the smallest 320px wide screens.

And depending on where you add that custom css override you might need to set the `!important` flag like this:

```html
.custom-logo-link img {
    max-width: 300px !important;
}
```